# gnu C condition of "if"

Tags: c, gnu

we got `if(expression) {...}`  for example. We all know if expression is true, it will execute lines in braces. But what is "True" in C?
Is that != 0 means true as I think?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what the standard has to say.

> ### §6.8.4 Selection statements
>
> #### Syntax
>
> 1. `selection-statement:`
>       `if ( expression ) statement`
>       `if ( expression ) statement else statement`
>       `switch ( expression ) statement`
>
> ### §6.8.4.1 The `if` statement
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1. The controlling expression of an if statement shall have scalar type.
>
> #### Semantics
>
> 1. In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0. In the else form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is not executed.
> 2. An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the
>      syntax.

Comment: Just to clarify, a scalar type is an integer type, a pointer type, or a floating/real type.

Answer (score 3):

Any none-zero result tests as true.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, true is not-null in C and C++.